# C++ Assertion Failed on vector at runtime Expression: vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector, assertion

im gettin this really annoying error message. I know Im only new to this but it seems the type of thing I could figure out. Can anyone show me where im going wrong please?

The message at run time is:
***Debug Assertion Failed!
Program:
....
File: c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector
Line: 932
Expression: Vector subscript out of range***

and the code is

```
#include "VectorIntStorage.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void VectorIntStorage::Read(istream& r)
{
    char c[13];
    r >> c;
    r >> NumberOfInts; //gets number of ints for vector

    //numberVector = new std::vector<int> numberVector;

    for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfInts; i++)
    {
        r >> numberVector[i];
        cout << numberVector[i] << endl;

        if(_sortRead) //true
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
            {
                if(numberVector[i] < numberVector[k])
                {
                    int temp = numberVector[k];
                    numberVector[k] = numberVector[i];
                    numberVector[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void VectorIntStorage::Write(ostream& w)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfInts; i++)
    {
        w << numberVector[i] << endl;
        cout << numberVector[i] << endl;
    }
}

void VectorIntStorage::sortStd()
{
    sort(numberVector.begin(), numberVector.end());
}

void VectorIntStorage::sortOwn()
{
    quickSort(0, NumberOfInts - 1);
}

void VectorIntStorage::setReadSort(bool sort)
{
    _sortRead = sort;
}

void VectorIntStorage::quickSort(int left, int right)
{
     int i = left, j = right;
      int tmp;
      int pivot = numberVector[(left + right) / 2];

      while (i <= j)
      {
            while (numberVector[i] < pivot)
                  i++;
            while (numberVector[j] > pivot)
                  j--;
            if (i <= j) 
            {
                  tmp = numberVector[i];
                  numberVector[i] = numberVector[j];
                  numberVector[j] = tmp;
                  i++;
                  j--;
            }
      }

      if (left < j)
      {
            quickSort(left, j);
      }
      if (i < right)
      {
            quickSort(i, right);
      }
}

VectorIntStorage::VectorIntStorage(const VectorIntStorage& copying)
{
    //int *duplicate = new int[(copying.NumberOfInts)];
    //vector<int> *duplicate = new vector<int>;

    //std::copy(numberVector.begin(), numberVector.end(), duplicate);
    //numberVector = duplicate;
    //NumberOfInts = copying.NumberOfInts;
}

VectorIntStorage::VectorIntStorage(void)
{
}


VectorIntStorage::~VectorIntStorage(void)
{
}
```

Comment: We don't have line numbers so indicating what line that is would be helpfull

Comment: No line number, its a run time error, sorry, should have mentioned that

Comment: @Tanya - On call to which method is causing the assertion failure ?

Comment: I wish I knew, thats why I gave you the whole cpp code because its an error message box that comes up when I try to run it

Comment: You should try to use a debugger to find the method call which triggers the assert. How is numberVector initialized,btw? Is it long enough to use the subscript operator in VectorIntStorage::Read(..)?

Comment: as
std::vector<int> numberVector;

Comment: @Tanya - How are you initializing the size of `numberVector` to be `NumberOfInts` ?

Comment: with r >> NumberOfInts i think
oh my, i cant remember, is there some way I should be initialising them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't have enough information to say for sure, but I suspect the failing line is `r >> numberVector[i]`. I suppose you meant to say `int j; r >> j; numberVector.push_back(j);`

The problem is precisely what the error message says: your vector subscript (`i`) is out of range. Specifically, you never increase the size of your vector, so it is always of size 0. Thus, any use of `operator[]` is going to reference an out-of-range element.

Comment: Other than this reason, can this error show up when a memory leak has occurred ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just use `numberVector[i]` without calling `numberVector.resize()` first.

```
vector<int> vec;
vec[1] = 0; // fails - vec is empty so [1] is out of range
vec.resize(100);
vec[1] = 5; // ok, you can access vec[0] .. vec[99] now
vec.push_back(11); // Now the size is 101 elements, you can access vec[0] .. vec[100]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
r >> NumberOfInts; //gets number of ints for vector
```

From the above comment, it seems you need a vector of size `NumberOfInts`. But leaving the line as commented -

```
//numberVector = new std::vector<int> numberVector;
```

You are declaring the vector as -

```
std::vector<int> numberVector; // The size of the vector is 0
```

To perform the operation of `[]` on `numberVector`, it's size should be mentioned and should be in the valid range while declaration. Since it not mentioned while declaration, you need to do a `push_back` operation to dynamically increase the size of the vector.

```
for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfInts; i++)
{
    r >> numberVector[i];    // Size isnot initially mentioned while declaration 
                             // of the vector to do an `[]` operation
    cout << numberVector[i] << endl;
    // ....
```