# vector subscript out of range error in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, vector

I am trying to write a program that takes an input of of n integers, and finds out the one that occurs the maximum number of times in the given input. I am trying to run the program for t cases.
For this, I have implemented a counting sort like algorithm (perhaps a bit naiive), that counts the number of occurrences of each number in the input. In case there are multiple numbers with the same maximum occurrence, I need to return the smaller among those. For this, I implemented sorting.
The issue I am facing is, that every time I run the program on Visual C++, I am getting an error that tells "vector subscript out of range". Under Netbeans, it is generating a return value of 1 and exiting. Please help me find the problem

```
   #include <cstdio>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>


using namespace std;

int findmax(vector<int> a, int n)
{
    int i,ret;
    ret = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i <n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > ret) {
                ret = a[i]; 
        }
    }
    return ret;
}


int main() {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, n,m,r1,r2;
    vector<int> a;
    int t;
    vector<int> buff;

    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {

        cin>>n;
        a.clear();
        buff.clear();
        for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            cin>>a[i];
        }

        sort(a.begin(),a.end());
        m = findmax(a,n);
        for ( j = 0; j < m+1; j++) {
            buff[a[j]] = buff[a[j]] + 1;
        }
        k = findmax(buff,m+1);

        for ( i = 0; i < m+1; i++) {
            if (buff[i] == k) {
                 r1 = i;
                 r2 = buff[i];
                 break;
            }
        }

        cout<<r1<<" "<<r2<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This can be solved with a debugger, or simply by adding a bunch of extra `cout` statements to inspect all the indices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Assertion Failed on vector at runtime Expression: vector subscript out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736813/c-assertion-failed-on-vector-at-runtime-expression-vector-subscript-out-of-ra) - you never increase the size of your `vector`, therefore it's `0`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Sorry, using debugger is of no use

Comment: @javacoder990: Yes it is.  Just step through your program until its behaviour diverges from what you expect.  You have then found your bug.

Comment: You don't seem to fill `buff` at all.

Comment: @BrianRoach: thanks, but I tried the suggestion in the above question's "best answer", it does not help at all.

Comment: @javacoder990 - I fail to see why, as it's the exact reason you're getting the error, and the exact solution to your problem, the same as outlined in the answers below; you're accessing an index that doesn't exist - one beyond the size of your vector. `resize()`ing may be necessary if you need a pre-determined number of elements beyond what you push in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After `a.clear()` the vector doesn't have any members, and its size is 0.

Add a call to `a.resize(n)` to make it the proper size. You also need to resize `buff` to whatever size it needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

this line it's the culprit:

```
 cin>>a[i];
```

you must use push_back:

```
  cin >> temp;
  a.push_back(temp);
```

or resize(n) before:

```
    cin>>n;
    a.resize(n);
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
```

then you should pass you vector by reference to findmax

```
int findmax(vector<int> &a, int n)
...
```

Comment: Not `std::vector::reserve`, but rather `std::vector::resize` does what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't how you populate an array.

```
cin>>a[i];
```

You need to use the `push_back()` method or pre-allocate the appropriate size.

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned in a comment above, I did implement this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're illegally using indexes of your vector that don't exist (you never add any items to the vector). Since you know the size, you can resize it after you clear it:

```
a.clear();
a.resize(n);
buff.clear();
buff.resize(n);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        cin>>a[i];
    }
```

will be out of range. The vector, as you construct it, has zero size.