# What's wrong with this code? I can't read vector from file. Expression: vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, copy, ifstream

Hello I'm having problem with this copy iterator I'm not sure how to write the copy iterator correctly. I'm       getting just this error : "Expression: vector subscript out of range". My program always stops in the std::copy line. Anyway my compiler doesn't show me any warnings and another errors.

```
 ifstream fin("aFileName", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
 std::vector< aClass > aVector;
 std::copy(std::istream_iterator<aClass, char>(fin), 
 std::istream_iterator<aClass, char>(), aVector.begin());
```

Maybe the ofstream part of my program is written badly. But I'm not getting any error either any warning messages at this part.

```
ofstream fout("aFileName", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
std::copy(aVector.begin(), aVector.end(), 
std::ostream_iterator<aClass, char>(fout, " "));
```

I'm sorry for my english.

Comment: Use `std::back_inserter(aVector)`, your vector is empty.

Comment: Most likely your `fin` isn't being set properly. Try printing that out, and seeing if that actually is actually getting set to what you think it is. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100848/vector-subscript-out-of-range-error-in-c

Comment: @user657267 That should be an answer.

Comment: I used the std::back_inserter(aVector) and i got the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector can be constructed directly from iterators. There's no need to use `std::copy`.

```
std::vector<aClass> aVector(std::istream_iterator<aClass>(fin), (std::istream_iterator<aClass>()));
```

Comment: @user3923130 Could you post the definition of `aClass`?

Comment: @user3923130 Or even better a really small executable code that shows the behavior.

Comment: Oh sorry it works. I really thank you I jsut didn't rewrite the example name aVector. Really thank you and I am really sorry for my inattention.